# Can Cython .so files be used in C?

Tags: python, c, cython

I used Cython recently and discovered that it outputs a .so file. Can I use the .so file in my C program and if so, how do I implement that?

Comment: The so likely depends on many other files as well making it difficult.  If you know what's in it and how to call or access, you might be able to generate a header and dynamically link.  You can also try to access it via dlopen

Comment: You used Cpython recently? Cpython is the most common python bytecode compiler/interpreter (from python.org). Are you sure you do not mean cython, which actually kinda is similar to what you describe?

Comment: To answer your question, you could perhaps, with some effort, not unlike that in FFI, use a linker to achieve your goals.

Comment: Yeah sorry I meant cython

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, assuming that the SO file exports its internal functions to the dynamic linking scope, where a linker/library can find its functions (See `dlfcn.h`). From there, you can call the functions that you have in the SO file.

A very simple C code would look like this:

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    void* dlhandle = dlopen("path/to/your/library", RTLD_LAZY);
    assert(dlhandle != NULL);

    void (*function_name)(int func_params) = dlsym(dlhandle, "func_name");
    // Check for NULL again

    // Call your function etc
    return 0
}
```

Technically, you can also dynamically link to it as a system library too. I wouldn't recommend it though for a variety of reasons.